Unexpected :ssh_sftp :timeout after SIGINT
I’m trying to understand an unexpected :timeout during :ssh_sftp.start_channel/3. This is the flow of events:

A Broadway pipeline is running, using a BroadwayKafka producer
The application receives SIGINT and starts to shutdown
Broadway batchers execute Broadway.handle_batch/4, kicking off a series of synchronous events
The last of which is writing a file to a remote SFTP server

The precise timing:

SIGINT received: 15:39:26.382
First SFTP connection attempted: 15:39:27.618
First SFTP connection timeout: 15:39:32.620
The last Kafka consumer leaves the group and the app exits with 0: 15:39:52.711

So the connection “times out” before the app fully shuts down.
I have two threads I’m not sure how to pull on any further:
The fact that the timeouts occur about exactly 5s after the attempt makes me think there’s some other underlying timeout. But why would we only hit this timeout on SIGINT?
Maybe :timeout is a misleading error here and there’s something else going on entirely
Anybody have any ideas? I’m hoping there’s a magic “Ah you forgot about !” solution here.
I would expect the SFTP connections and finish writing before the application exited successfully.

5 seconds is a common default for timeouts in Elixir. E.g. maybe a process is trying to complete a task, but it terminates it if it isn't completed within 5 seconds.  You can explicitly set the allowable timeout (e.g. to :infinity).   How long does the task take?  What would be odd is if this took longer during the shutdown process than it does during the regular running.

@Everett That is the odd thing indeed. This task succeeds 100% of the time when not shutting down. I've considered some other layer being at fault here-- we're in a nomad cluster, in a docker container here. So perhaps one of these layers is doing.... something... to cause this delay.

Perhaps some dependency got shut down first?

That was a thought as well. But as far as I can tell, these timeouts occur before any direct or transient dependencies are shut off-- OTP apps included. Sasl and OTP reports are being logged.
